# How to implement a bunch of similar classes

Tags: c++, boost, crtp

My task is to define the specification class of the device which consists of various amount of properties. For example, Device1 specification contains Property1, Property2. Some other Device2 contains Property1 only, DeviceX specification contains Property5, Property6 etc.

In order to avoid repeating similar implementations for those setProperty methods, I decided to store them in separate classes and to derive the bunch of specifications out of them.

There is a bunch of quite similar classes containing specialized methods using CRTP idiom. CRTP is used in order to access the setParameter method of SPECIFICATION class:

```
template<typename SPECIFICATION>
struct Property1
{
    void setProperty1( const double & Value)
    {
        static_cast<SPECIFICATION*>(this)->setParameter( "Property1", Value);
    }
};

template<typename SPECIFICATION>
struct Property2
{
    void setProperty2( const double & Value)
    {
        static_cast<SPECIFICATION*>(this)->setParameter( "Property2", Value);
    }
};
```

These templated classes are then used in respect to CRTP idiom:

```
template<typename DEVICE_TYPE>
class Device
{
public:
        class Specification;
};

template<>
class Device<DeviceTypeAAA>::Specification
        :   public Property1<Specification>,
            public Property2<Specification>
{
};

template<>
class Device<DeviceTypeBBB>::Specification
        :   public Property1<Specification>
{
};

template<>
class Device<DeviceTypeCCC>::Specification
        :   public Property2<Specification>
{
};
```

As visible from the code snippet above, the Device's specification is 'assembled' using the inheritance of required Properties. All Devices are specialized classes of Device::Specification.

QUESTION: As there are really many "Property classes" implementing "setProperty" methods and quite many Device specification classes, I am courious to know whether there is some elegant method how to implement this bunch of similar classes more code efficient. I thought about using boost::mpl::vector in cooperation with boost linear inheritance to define the list of all properties the device shall derive... Maybe I am following completely wrong direction is implementing this. Please let me know if you think so.

If you have some idea how to optimize the implemetation, I would be very glad. Many thanks to anybody willing to help!

Answer (score 0):

The implementation below use variadics template, but leads to a possibly long stack of inheritance, but it should not be a problem.

Except that, it does the job, reducing definition of specification to one inheritance declaration with a list of properties.

It compiles and runs well on GCC 4.7 (C++11) and more, and also on clang 3.8.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename SPECIFICATION>
struct Property1
{
    void setProperty1( const double & Value)
    {
        static_cast<SPECIFICATION*>(this)->setParameter( "Property1", Value);
    }
};

template<typename SPECIFICATION>
struct Property2
{
    void setProperty2( const double & Value)
    {
        static_cast<SPECIFICATION*>(this)->setParameter( "Property2", Value);
    }
};

template<typename SPECIFICATION, template<typename> class ... PROPERTIES>
struct Properties; // primary-template

template <typename SPECIFICATION, 
          template<typename> class PROPERTY, 
          template<typename> class ... PROPERTIES>
struct Properties<SPECIFICATION, PROPERTY, PROPERTIES...> : 
       PROPERTY<SPECIFICATION>, 
       Properties<SPECIFICATION, PROPERTIES...>{}; // head specialisation 

template <typename SPECIFICATION, 
          template<typename> class PROPERTY>
struct Properties<SPECIFICATION, PROPERTY> : 
       PROPERTY<SPECIFICATION>{}; // tail specisalization

template<typename DEVICE_TYPE>
class Device
{
public:
        class Specification;
};

struct DeviceTypeAAA{};
struct DeviceTypeBBB{};
struct DeviceTypeCCC{};

template<>
class Device<DeviceTypeAAA>::Specification
        :   public Properties<Specification, Property1, Property2>
{
    public:
    void setParameter(const std::string &name, double value){
        std::cout << "DeviceTypeAAA: "  << name << " = " << value << "\n";
    }
};

template<>
class Device<DeviceTypeBBB>::Specification
        :   public Properties<Specification, Property1>
{
    public:
    void setParameter(const std::string &name, double value){
        std::cout << "DeviceTypeBBB: "  << name << " = " << value << "\n";
    }
};

template<>
class Device<DeviceTypeCCC>::Specification
        :   public Properties<Specification, Property2>
{
    public:
    void setParameter(const std::string &name, double value){
        std::cout << "DeviceTypeCCC : "  << name << " = " << value << "\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
  Device<DeviceTypeAAA>::Specification a{};
  Device<DeviceTypeBBB>::Specification b{};
  Device<DeviceTypeCCC>::Specification c{};

  a.setProperty1(2.);
  a.setProperty2(2.);

  b.setProperty1(2.);
  b.setProperty2(2.); // compiler error, no member setProperty2

  c.setProperty1(2.);  // compiler error setProperty1
  c.setProperty2(2.);


}
```